# Why Objective-C++ singleton's props can't be set?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I have a singleton class written in Objective-C. Its purpose is to hold state.

If I compile it as Objective-C code (implementation is in .m file), the init method successfully sets the default values for all props.

But if I rename the implementation file to .mm and compile it as Objective-C++, I clearly see stepping-through with the Debugger, that the props can't be set in the init method.

Here is the header:

```c
// State.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface State : NSObject {
    @private
        SomeType* someObject;
        int someNumber;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeType* someObject;
@property int someNumber;

+ (State*)singleton;

@end
```

And this is the implementation:

```c
// State.mm

#import "State.h"

static State* singleton = nil;


@implementation State

@synthesize someObject = someObject,
            someNumber = someNumber;

+ (State*)singleton {
    @synchronized([State class]) {
        if (!singleton) {
            singleton = [[self alloc] init];
        }
        return singleton;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (id)init {
    if ( singleton != nil ) {
        return singleton;
    }

    if (self = [super init]) {
        someObject = NULL;
        someNumber = 44100;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you expand on "the props can't be set"? What happens? An exception, a silent failure, a random other value, or something else?

Comment: I copied and pasted this into a new project, and it works just fine (though that's probably not the best way to implement a singleton in Objective-C).

Answer (score 4):

You are deviating from generally accepted rules in many ways.

One. Singletons are created using dispatch_once. (Fill in the details appropriately; Xcode will help you).

```
+ (MySingleton*)singleton {
    static MySingleton* singleton;
    dispatch_once (^{ singleton = [[MySingleton alloc] init]; });
    return singleton; 
}
```

Two. No weird stuff in init. It's a singleton. Anyone calling alloc/init gets what they deserve.

Three. Do not use instance variables with the same names as properties. No declaring of private instance variables, no @synthesize. The instance variables will start with _.

Four. Don't believe the debugger. Use NSLog.

Comment: Yes, better to use -(instancetype) init NS_UNAVAILABLE; instead of such weird initializer.